# Incomprehension in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I want when I click button my textbox1 must change, but textbox3 not
Why does not it **work**?

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button"/>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
             </ContentTemplate>
    <br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I Click **Button1** my **TextBox3** changes
**Why**?

Comment: Sorry! <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> will after    </asp:UpdatePanel>

Answer (score 3):

Because when you click the button you submit a request to the server, which results in a round-trip, which results in `Page_Load` being executed again. You can avoid this by detecting whether the request is part of the postback cycle using the `IsPostBack` property:

```
if (IsPostBack) {

}
```

Or, as is in most cases, doing stuff when it's *not* a postback:

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
  TextBox3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```